# MATLAB: Accessing Multidimensional Cell Matrix Index

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have cell matrix which the dimensions are changing according to user input. As a user, I want to use one dimension's certain index meanwhile whole the elements of the other dimensions exist. I think it is better to explain the situation with a certain example:
Assume that my cell matrix A whose sizes are `2x3x4x5x7`. I want to use whole elements of `1.`,`3.` and `4. dimension`. At the same time only the `2. element` of the `2. dimension` and `3., 5. elements` of `5. dimension`. This can be achieved easily with :

```
A(:,2,:,:,[3 5]);
```

What about the case A is input of a function and dimensions are changing. How can I obtain this result with linear indexing or another way? 
I know that there is no such a syntax but my situation can be described as follows:

```
whole_indexes = sub2ind(size(A),[:,2,:,:,[3,5]]);
A(whole_indexes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved the with the code below:

```
size_A          = size(A); % A is the matrix whose elements will be selected
whole_index     = cellfun(@(x) 1:x,num2cell(size_A),'UniformOut',false); % create a cell array which includes all the possible numbers
all_sizes       = cellfun(@length,whole_index); % each dimension size
%% select the desired indexes in your desired dimensions
whole_index{1}  = [1 2]; % first dimension first 2 elements
whole_index{2}  = [2];   % second dimension second element
all_numbers     = combvec(whole_index{:}).'; % whole possibilities
all_numbers     = mat2cell(all_numbers,max(size_nums),ones(1,min(size_nums))); % cell format of possibilities
comb_inds       = sub2ind(all_sizes,all_numbers{:}); 
desired_out     = A(comb_inds);
```

Another solution would be written like:

```
    size_A          = size(A); % A is the matrix whose elements will be selected
    whole_index     = cellfun(@(x) 1:x,num2cell(size_A),'UniformOut',false); 
    %% select the desired indexes in your desired dimensions
    whole_index{1}  = [1 2]; % first dimension first 2 elements
    whole_index{2}  = [2];   % second dimension second element
    desired_out     = A(whole_index{:});
```